# Graphical Issues After Using Windows Live Mesh Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, visual-artifacts, windows-live-mesh

I was using Windows Live Mesh's Remote Desktop feature to use my PC from my laptop. After disconnecting and returning to my PC's monitor when I turned it on my graphics were all messed up. Here's exactly what happened:

- Logged on to WLM
- Started remote desktop
- VIA remote desktop I changed my PC's resolution to 1366x768 from 1680x1050 by right-clicking the desktop and going to "Screen resolution".
- After changing the resolution I noticed that on the remote desktop view there was a weird artifact-looking ripple on the right side of the screen, I ignored this because I thought it was just Remote Desktop doing it.
- Used Remote Desktop like normal, disconnected from the PC

Then after I walked over to use my PC and when I turned on the monitor it was at the Windows 7 login screen and it looked normal, but after I logged in everything was all miscolored and artifact-y.

I noticed that the discoloration only happens when I am using the GPU for my display, for instance if I disable the GPU from the Device Manager it looks normal (because It's running off of whatever it defaults to when there are no drivers or whatever).

I tried reinstalling nVidia drivers with 'clean install' checked but as soon as it finished it went back to messed up. I also noticed that the login screen will look normal if I restart and the artifacts reappear as soon as I log in. Another thing is that the mouse cursor appears to be normal with no miscoloration or anything.

Here are my specs:

- Windows 7 Professional 32-bit
- [EVGA nVidia GeForce GTX460](http://amzn.com/B003VWW2KK)

Here's what the artifacting looks like next to a screencap I took while trying to capture the artifacting, the screencap just turned out looking like normal so I just took a picture of my screen:

<-- Normal/Artifacting -->
[image: Image of artifacting vs normal desktop]

I'm hoping this is fixable... or did my GPU just die? :(

Comment: I just tried retracing my steps and basically recreated the whole incident except before disconnecting from Remote Desktop I set the resolution back to 1680x1050. Afterwards the artifacts were still there but I tried restarting my PC and when it came back the artifacts were gone.

I have no idea what caused it all but it sounds like it might be a serious bug with Remote Desktop.

Comment: Ok I opened Windows Live Mesh up again, and AS SOON as I enabled remote connection the artifacts reappeared again. I think it might have something to do with the Remote Connection service or something, any ideas?